# How to get Jenkins list of job details using Jenkins client in Java

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am searching some Jenkins client frameworks to deal with Jenkins server.I have found a good and updated Jenkins client server API called [RisingOak/jenkins-client](https://github.com/RisingOak/jenkins-client)

Connectivity with Jenkins Server

```
JenkinsServer jenkins = new JenkinsServer(new URI("http://localhost:8080/jenkins"), "admin", "password")
```

I have setup multiple projects in Jenkins so i want to get list of jobs details for each project using Jenkings client like in Jenkings server left side list.

If anyone families with RisingOak/jenkins-client or any other APIs Please let me know how to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally looked deep into RisingOak/jenkins-client and found a way to achieve it.

```
JenkinsServer js = new JenkinsServer(URI.create("Your Jenkins URL"));
MavenJobWithDetails mavenJob = js.getMavenJob("Your project Name inside server");
//get last Successful build
BuildWithDetails details = mavenJob.getLastSuccessfulBuild().details();
//get job details
 System.out.println("Build Number: " + details.getNumber());
```

or iterate list of jobs

```
for(MavenBuild items : mavenJob.getBuilds())
 {

    details=items.details();
    System.out.println(details.getFullDisplayName());
 }
```

More details [here](https://github.com/RisingOak/jenkins-client/blob/master/src/test/java/com/offbytwo/jenkins/integration/BuildJobTestReports.java).